# Can I get a SelectList in my view model to render using EditorForModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I would like have a listbox of states render using the EditorForModel Html helper.
My view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyewModel()
    {
        States = new SelectList(MyModel.RegionsToSelectList,"Value","Text");
    }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "States")]
    public SelectList States { get; private set; }
}
```

In my view I have `@Html.EditorForModel()`
The `City` renders properly but the `States` do not render into any sort of list (dropdown or listbox)

If I use `@Html.DropDownList("mylistname", Model.States)` it renders properly.
I would really like to have it render in the `ForModel` process.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Html.DropdownListFor helper if you want to generate a drop down list. The fact that you have used SelectList as type to some of your properties doesn't mean that the default editor template will render a  box. So you will have to write a custom editor template.

You may take a look at the following [blog post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) to see how those default templates are implemented.